# Any recommendation on my.cnf on aws.large instance?

Tags: mysql, percona

Any best recommendation variables for my.cnf on percona server on a high 256GB RAM and 32 CPU with 4000 IOPS?

How about below ones?

```
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=180G 
> innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
> innodb_flush_neighbors=0
```

any other recommendations on Mysql percona 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

With that kind of AWS instance, you must be planning heavy writes.

I would add the following

```
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 32M
innodb_read_io_threads  = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
```

Comment: how about innodb_buffer_pool_instances? This is new in 5.6 onwards. Do we get some real benifits out of it?

Comment: The default is already 8 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances). That's fine.